# Changing spark standalone master port on windows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark (as of today). I have just installed in windows and seems to be running fine. The standalone master port for spark is 8080 which I need to change.

My understanding is that the change is made in conf/spark-env.cmd.

I see load-spark-env.cmd in the bin directory. This ends with the following block:

```
:LoadSparkEnv
if exist "%user_conf_dir%\spark-env.cmd" (
  call "%user_conf_dir%\spark-env.cmd"
 )
```

But I don't see spark-env.cmd in my conf dir. Nonetheless, spark does seem to start up cleanly when I run it.

Can someone advise me on how to proceed?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

> #### Cluster Managers Each cluster manager in Spark has additional configuration options. Configurations can be found on the pages for each mode: #### YARN #### Mesos #### Standalone Mode # Environment Variables Certain Spark settings can be configured through environment variables, which are read from the `conf/spark-env.sh` script in the directory where Spark is installed (or `conf/spark-env.cmd` on Windows). In Standalone and Mesos modes, this file can give machine specific information such as hostnames. It is also sourced when running local Spark applications or submission scripts. Note that `conf/spark-env.sh` does not exist by default when Spark is installed. However, you can copy `conf/spark-env.sh.template` to create it. Make sure you make the copy executable. The following variables can be set in `spark-env.sh`: